# Not able to migrate Google Cloud project from personal account to organisation

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I had created a project using my personal google account. This project is also associated with Firebase. We have now created an organisation account but unable to link the project from the personal account to the organisation account. My personal google account has also been added as owner of organisation but still I'm unable to move the project. Kindly help on this.

Comment: In GCP an Organization [1] is the root resource which contains the projects. To migrate your project you will have to follow the steps provided on this page [2].
You can further read this article on the Google Cloud Platform Blog which explains how to organize your GCP organization [3].
___
[1]: https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/creating-managing-organization
[2]: https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/migrating-projects-billing [3]: https://cloudplatform.googleblog.com/2017/05/mapping-your-organization-with-the-Google-Cloud-Platform--resource-hierarchy.html

Answer (score 4):

To migrate your personal project to the new organisation account [1](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/migrating-projects-billing) you will first need to make sure your personal account has the right permissions on both sides:
-Assign to your personal google account Project Creator role on the new Organization
-On the project you are migrating, assign to your account the following roles: Project Mover, Project Owner, or Project Editor (If you don't have these roles, the target organization won't appear in the GCP Console as a choice for migration)

You can migrate your project using the Console:
Open the IAM & admin > Settings page in the GCP Console.
Click Select, then select No Organization from the Organization list.
Select the project you want to migrate, then click Migrate.
On the Organization list, select the organization you want to migrate your project to.

You can also use a simple gcloud command:

```
$ gcloud alpha projects move PROJECT_ID --organization ORGANIZATION_ID
```

If you want to use the API this is the snippet:

```
project = crm.projects().get(projectId=flags.projectId).execute()
project['parent'] = {
    'type': 'organization',
    'id': flags.organizationId
}

project = crm.projects().update(
projectId=flags.projectId, body=project).execute()
```

Caution: Be aware that once you migrate a project, there is no way back!

You can further read this article on the Google Cloud Platform Blog which explains how to organize your GCP organization [2](https://cloudplatform.googleblog.com/2017/05/mapping-your-organization-with-the-Google-Cloud-Platform--resource-hierarchy.html).

---

Comment: do you know if the associated firebase project is migrated too?

Comment: "Project Editor" no longer exists. And "Project Owner" is now "Owner". Will this still work without it?

Answer (score 0):

Gcloud has been updated since 2020, the gcloud command to migrate a personal project to a new organisation is :

```
$ gcloud beta projects move PROJECT_ID --DESTINATION_TYPE DESTINATION_ID
```

Where:

- PROJECT_ID is the ID or number of the project you wish to move.
- DESTINATION_TYPE is either **organization** or folder.
- DESTINATION_ID is the ID of the organization resource or folder to which you want to move the project. You can only specify one target.

And using the API here's the request :

```
POST https://cloudresourcemanager.googleapis.com/v3/{name=PROJECT_NAME}:move
{
  "destinationParent": DESTINATION_PARENT
}
```

You can find futher information on online [GCloud documentation](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/moving-projects-folders#api)